# Cannot start ElasticSerach on windows , fails with message about xpack.security.autoconfiguration.enabled

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having a really weird problem with ElasticSearch 7.16.3 on my Windows 10 machine.
It was working fine , and then i just tried to add 2 inline variables in the elasticsearch.yaml file namely:

```
xpack.security.autoconfiguration.enabled=true
xpack.security.enabled=true
```

so then i started my elasticsearch from the /bin folder using elasticsearch.bat , and i got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [xpack.security.autoconfiguration.enabled] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:561)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:507)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:477)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:447)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsModule.<init>(SettingsModule.java:137)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:500)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:234)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:234)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:434)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:166)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:157)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
```

after some googling it turned out that variable is no longer supported in ElasticSearch 7.17 , and XPack comes by default.
So i removed those 2 Lines from the yaml, and then the problem persisted.I have tried first
with

```
elasticsearch.bat -Epurge_cache=true
```

same error message as above, i double and tripple checked the .yaml file, the lines are no longer in there.
Then i deleted the programfiles/elasticsearch folder and copied the old downloaded default one
again same error.I have then restarted the PC, now again the same error, what is going on here ??
Any ideas are apprecietaed

Answer (score 0):

[xpack.security.autoconfiguration.enabled settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-settings.html) released on Elasticsearch v8 so yes you can't use on elasticsearch v7.

After updating the elasticsearch.yml and removing the not supported settings and RESTART the elasticsearch it should get the new elasticsearch.yml and start to work.

After restarting Elasticsearch, if you see the same error again that means elasticsearch still using the old YAML. Check the elasticsearch service and make sure the service using the correct/updated elasticsearch.yml.